# No best common type exists among return expressions

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, meteor-collection2, angular2-meteor

When I use [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) in angular2-meteor project, these kinds of codes from [demo](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) always give me warning in the terminal:

> No best common type exists among return expressions.

How can I improve the codes? Thanks

```
{
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    autoValue: function() {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return new Date();
      } else if (this.isUpsert) {
        return {$setOnInsert: new Date()};
      } else {
        this.unset();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's telling you precisely what the error is.  You're returning a Date, an object, and whatever is returned by this.unset() (probably nothing, that seems like a void).  So you have absolutely ZERO common return types.  Pick a type and return that type consistently.

Comment: @DavidL thanks, I tried to add a `return undefined;` after `this.unset();`, but it still gives me the warning.

Comment: `autoValue` function doesn't have appropriate return type and also `this.unsert` is not clear. set some return type to that function.

Comment: The codes are from demo. I don't know how to return same type correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since a type of Date is expected for EVERY return branch, you must return a Date type for every if/else branch OR you can create a union that returns two different types.

In either case, you can return null for the third condition if the type is Date.  That is valid in typescript.

```
autoValue: function() : Date|Object  {
    if (this.isInsert) {
        return new Date();
    } else if (this.isUpsert) {
        return {$setOnInsert: new Date()};
    } else {
        this.unset();
        return null;
    }
}
```