# Typescript function with 'any' type registers 'No best common type' error anyway

Tags: angular, typescript

I keep getting the No best common type error despite the fact that I have assigned the function 'any' type. I've also tried combination of types like 'any|string', 'string|any'. . . Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
export class TestClass {
  gotCode: any;

  constructor() {

     this.gotCode = function(){
        var codes = Lodash.compact(Lodash.map(Parse.User.current().get("blah"), function(n){
           if(moment().isBefore(n.endDate) && moment().isAfter(n.startDate)){
              return n;
           }
        }));

        if (codes.length > 0){
           return {endDate: Lodash.first(codes).endDate, codeId: Lodash.first(codes).objectId, consumerMatchingCardCash: Lodash.first(codes).consumerMatchingCardCash, codeName: Lodash.first(codes).codeName, consumerPercentIncreaseOnCashBack: Lodash.first(codes).consumerPercentIncreaseOnCashBack};
        } else{
           return "No Codes";
        }
     }();
  }
}
```

I took a look at the existing pages:
[Type inference with union types - No best common type exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479746/type-inference-with-union-types-no-best-common-type-exists)

[Angular2: No best common type exists among return expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440878/angular2-no-best-common-type-exists-among-return-expressions)

[No best common type exists among return expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231334/no-best-common-type-exists-among-return-expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just declare the method on the class. Also to get round the 'no best common type error set the return type of the function to any.

```
  export class TestClass {
    constructor() {
    }

    gotCode(): any {
      let codes = Lodash.compact(Lodash.map(Parse.User.current().get('blah'), function (n) {
        if (moment().isBefore(n.endDate) && moment().isAfter(n.startDate)) {
          return n;
        }
      }));

      if (codes.length > 0) {
        return {
          endDate: Lodash.first(codes).endDate,
          codeId: Lodash.first(codes).objectId,
          consumerMatchingCardCash: Lodash.first(codes).consumerMatchingCardCash,
          codeName: Lodash.first(codes).codeName,
          consumerPercentIncreaseOnCashBack: Lodash.first(codes).consumerPercentIncreaseOnCashBack
        };
      } else {
        return 'No Codes';
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar enough with Typescript to say why the error is occurring (I don't think `any` in Typescript is the "root" type and thus common to all other types the way `object` is in C# or Java but I'm not sure.) You should be able to fix your error though by giving your function an explicit return type:

```
export class TestClass {
    gotCode: any;

    constructor() {
        this.gotCode = function():any { // <- Add the return type here
            /* Your code here... */
        }();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't put ':any' here like you have it as it throws an error: "this.gotCode = function():any { // <- Add the return type here". Other suggestions?

Comment: What is the error? Similar code compiles for me, and setting the return type to `any` is the solution you accepted in JayChase's answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what was going on. It turned out ok. I think there may be a bug somewhere in the Ionic/Angular 2 rebuild system.